# What is the best way to read/write data with javascript?

Tags: javascript, database, reactjs, storage

I want a way to really simply read/write to a json file (as my storage) online. I want to be able to host an app and make axios requests to this to read the data, update it locally and then push the data to the online resource. is there any simple way to do this?

I've used firebase in the passed but this is too long for me to set up now. also http://myjson.com/ only seems to let me do reads. there must be a quick way to host data in a json format that allows reads and writes

I also don't want to use localstorage because other people will be accessing the app

Answer (score 0):

I think it's unfortunate your question is getting down-voted - but that's because the premise of your question is off. Reading/writing a single JSON file is expensive (e.g. timewise) and would be a naive approach (that's okay, we've all been there). What you want is a database. I would suggest starting off with a simple database such as [mlab](https://mlab.com/). But even before that, I would suggest you read this [article](https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-connect-to-an-api-with-javascript/) - it gives a good overview of what a CRUD app is.

---

But if you really want to use a JSON file (again, I would highly NOT recommend this). Then:

1. You'll need to setup a server
2. Expose an API endpoint (where you handle GET/POST etc requests) for that server, so clients/people can communicate with said server
3. Have the server talk to some kind of store (e.g. https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) where the file would live

steps 1. and 2. you'll eventually need to do for any server. But step 3. is why I would NOT recommend using a JSON file. That's because it's very expensive (as noted before) to get the file, change the file, and then put that file back in the store. At that point, you might as well use a database.

Good luck! :)